# Autoloading of classes through composer does not work

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, psr-4

I have a project structure:

[image]

In the index.php I create 2 new objects:

```
use App\Controllers\Test;
use Xuborx\Cms\App;

new Test();
new App();
```

My Test.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Test
{

}
```

My App.php

```
<?php

namespace Xuborx\Cms;

class App {

}
```

My autoload object in composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Controllers\\": "app/controllers",
            "Xuborx\\Cms\\": "vendor/xuborx/cms"

        }
    }
```

Object Test created successfully in the index.php, but when I am creating new App, I have an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Xuborx\Cms\App' not found in
> /home/denis/Coding/xuborx-cms/public/index.php:8 Stack trace: #0
> {main} thrown in /home/denis/Coding/xuborx-cms/public/index.php on
> line 8

Also, when I run **composer dump-autoload -o**, I get error:

> Class Xuborx\Cms\App located in ./vendor/xuborx/cms/core/App.php does
> not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.

I think, I not correct use autoload in composer.json, but I don't understand my error. Please< talk me about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App.php are inside /core directory :

```
autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Controllers\\": "app/controllers",
            "Xuborx\\Cms\\": "vendor/xuborx/cms/core"

        }
    }
```